# Convert a date into word format | Javascript | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have this date :
2/19/2017
As of the time posting this, this would be tomorrow. I would like to know how I can convert a date into a verbage such as this.

Another example, 2/21/2017. This would become 'Next Week'. 
And 3/25/2017 would become 'Next Month'.
4/25/2018 would be 'Next Year'.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't to use Moment.js. It has very good utilities to manipulate dates.

Have a look at [Humanize](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/), [Weeks](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/) and other methods. They are right choice for your need.

For example, look at the below code.

*Note: Ignore warning and scroll down to see the result. Warning is related to your date format. You should fix that.*

```js
var aDate = moment('10/21/2017');
var now = moment();

document.write(moment.duration( now.diff(aDate) ).humanize() );
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into MomentJS library and plugins for it http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/